# Image not showing when sharing to FB

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, share

I'm using the command "FB.ShareLink" to share a FB post.
When i try to share this picture: 
http://sheep-service.info/TheOfficeQuest/Pics/pic.png

It share the post with empty picture.

But, when i try to share the same picture from different location:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSFdm.png

It shares the post with this picture.

So my questions is: Why does the picture shows only from the second location? do i need to configure something on my facebook app page?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsheep-service.info%2FTheOfficeQuest%2FPics%2Fpic.png - that server returns a 404 not found when the FB scraper requests the image.

Comment: I already tried that, i can see that something is wrong with what my server is returning, my questions is what do i need to do so my server will return a valid response? (Do i need to write HTML code instead of putting PNG file?)

Comment: No, you need to figure out why your server responds with status code 404 when the FB scraper requests that URL. Since it doesn’t when it is requested by a normal browser, it is probably some plugin/config setting/... that tries to block requests by “bots”.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will check it!

Comment: @CBroe, i checked and did not find anything. This is a new AWS instance. Do you have idea where should i search?